# Is there a connection between The Establishment Clause and the fact that The United States has never fought a war in the name of Religion?

Tags: war, religion, us-constitution

Since the drafting and enactment of The Establishment Clause-(The First Amendment and The Freedom of Religion) in 1791, the United States has never fought a war in the name of religion. The U.S. has never declared war....on behalf of religion.....nor has America ever defended itself as the protectorate of religion.

Is this directly attributable to the historical legacy of The Establishment Clause?

Comment: Consider that the vast majority of wars fought by the United States were undeclared.

Comment: Okay, that may be true, but how does it answer the question regarding the likely correlation between The Establishment Clause and the fact that the United States has never fought a war in the name of religion?

Comment: SPaveln comment is relevant since, as few wars have been declared, there are few formal explanations for warsb si the sample size is not relevant. Correlation is not causation. The USA was established in an historical context in which the divine right of kings and religion war were already falling out of favor. And even that did not prevent prosecution of Mormons, for example. And it would remain to be argued how much religion did factor in treatment and wars with native Americans or non Protestant countries (Mexico).

Comment: Perhaps it would be better idea to post a question at [law.se] adding it the establishment cause would forbid a President to declare war for religious reasons. My take would be that the answer is that would be allowed.

Comment: Some wars have been fought for 2 religions: the god of oil and the god of natural resources.

Comment: The US is mostly Christian, and by the time of its establishment the Christian wars of religion war largely over.

Comment: The Wars of Religion were long over by the time the US became a country.  For that matter, they were mostly over before serious colonization efforts in North America began.

Comment: These are all interesting answers, though unfortunately, none have satisfactorily answered the basic point of the question.  Does The Establishment Clause in the U.S. Bill of Rights have any connection to the longevity of external and internal peace-(that is to say, is there a connection between this time honored amendment and the unreligious nature of American warfare over the centuries?

Answer (score 2):

For comparison, let's look at the UK which has an established state church, and also got involved in plenty of wars since 1791. We don't see any waged *in the name of religion* here either. Overall, the Napoleonian wars started a shift away from religion as the best motivator for war to nationalism. I'd thus say that the US never overtly waging war in the name of religion can already be explained by the date of its foundation.

Comment: Actually, much of British involvement in the Ottoman empire was either in the name of protecting the rights of christians or countering similar attempts by Russia. Then there is the whole issue of the special status of the holy places in Palestine negotiated by Sykes and Picot.

Comment: @RogerV. I'm not claiming that the UK's foreign policy was entirely void of references to Christianity. I'm just saying that "waging war in the name of religion" is something they didn't really do from the 19th century onwards.